# Use courier font inline on text

Tags: fonts

If I want to apply the courier font to a small piece of text in my file, how can I do that? I have searched around but can't seem to find information for the courier font.

Comment: By 'courier', are you actually referring to 'typewriter' (as part of the Computer Modern fonts, or to the specific mono-spaced font 'Courier'?

Comment: I mean the specific mono-spaced font - Courier, that is typically used for programming code.

Comment: Courier is a very wide font. There are further mono-space fonts available if you are free to choose.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Link appears broken.

Comment: @Iplodman Oops! I'd recommend [Inconsolata](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use the [`courier` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/courier). Consequently, the minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}
\begin{document}
This is not Courier font. \texttt{This is Courier font.}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

produces

[image: Courier font in LaTeX]

There is a marginal difference between the output generated via `\texttt{...}` with/without the `courier` package:

- Without `courier` package:

[image: Typewriter font in LaTeX]

- With `courier` package:

[image: Courier font in LaTeX]

Comment: Dear Werner. Can we apply courier font for the formula also?

Comment: @anonimo: Start here: [Math symbols in tt font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119879/5764)

Answer (score 57):

Is `\texttt{}` what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Here is some \texttt{fixed width} text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a difference between the output generated via `\texttt{...}` to what is produced when using the `courier` package.

Comment: Even though there's a difference, Peter's answer is a good addition. Most viewers, like me, come here for the `\texttt` option as it is difficult to ask Google the question relevant to `\texttt`.