# bracket as ordinary symbol in math mode

Tags: brackets, typewriter, mathcode

I would like to to write in math mode using tt font and everything ok, but brackets. The next code

```
$ \mathtt{[x + y]} $
```

get

[image: ploho]

but i would like to get

[image: horosho].

It can be done by some additional commands

```
$ \mathtt{\texttt{[}x + y\texttt{]}} $
```

Is there any way get desirable result without any additions?

I try to write definition for active symbol

```
\def\lbr{[}
\begingroup
\catcode`[=\active
\gdef[{\texttt{[}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`[="8000}
```

but it looks like replacement performs recursively.

Another way i think that it is necessary to change mathcode for [ to mathcode of letters but do not find solution.

Addition

The solution

```
\def\lbr{[}
\begingroup
\catcode`[=\active
\gdef[{\texttt{\lbrack}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`[="8000}
```

works correctly with `\gdef[{\texttt{\lbrack}}`

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  if you're representing math with the `\tt` font, it's not likely to look a lot different than if your simply set it all as `\texttt{[x + y]}`.  you might try that to see if it's acceptable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you! yes! but i would like to write $ \mathtt{\int f[x] dx} $

Comment: that's harder.  first, you need a font with a `\tt` integral.  (would have been useful to have that requirement in the question.)  if a suitable font can be found that is accessed by unicode, it might still be possible to treat it as `\texttt` with `utf8` encoding.  but this too falls apart as soon as you want non-numeric superscripts or subscripts -- that really does need math markup.  i have to leave that to someone else to address.

Comment: if you load package `mathastext` it will do that (see `1.8 Extended scope of the math alphabets commands` in its manual), il you emit `\MTnonlettersobeymathxx`.

Comment: @jfbu i ve just find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119879/math-symbols-in-tt-font tank you!!

Comment: I had forgotten about `\Mathtt` defined by `mathastext`! you can use this with `mathastext` in *subdued* mode, as explained at the https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119879/math-symbols-in-tt-font that you found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the mathcode of `[` and `]`, when you want to use them in their definitions as active characters.

Of course, the extended brackets cannot be from the monospaced font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mathttfont}{OT1}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathtt}{mathttfont}

\edef\keptlbrack{\mathchar\the\mathcode`[}
\edef\keptrbrack{\mathchar\the\mathcode`]}
\begingroup
\catcode`[=\active \catcode`]=\active
\gdef[{%
  \ifnum\mathgroup=\symmathttfont
    \mathopen{\mathchar\numexpr"7000+`\[\relax}
  \else
    \keptlbrack
  \fi
}
\gdef]{%
  \ifnum\mathgroup=\symmathttfont
    \mathclose{\mathchar\numexpr"7000+`\]\relax}
  \else
    \keptrbrack
  \fi
}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathcode`\[="8000 \mathcode`\]="8000
}

\begin{document}

$[\mathtt{x+y}]$

$\mathtt{[x+y]}$

$\displaystyle\left[\frac{a}{b}\right]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I adapted my answer from here: [How can I make every occurrence of `+` and `-` be replaced by a macro, but only in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392072/how-can-i-make-every-occurrence-of-and-be-replaced-by-a-macro-but-only), borrowing liberally from here: [How to set temporary math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385013/how-to-set-temporary-math-font/385068#385068).

The result is that `[` and `]` get converted in math mode to the `\texttt` equivalent, but that `\big` and family as well as `\left...\right` are unaffected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%% FROM https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385013/how-to-set-temporary-math-font/385068#385068
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareMathVersion{ttmath}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{ttmath}{OT1}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}
\xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\mathversion{ttmath}}{}{}
%%%%% ADAPTED FROM 
%%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392338/bracket-as-ordinary-symbol-in-math-mode/392350#392350
\makeatletter
% Commands that take the original meanings of the special characters
\let\lbr[
\let\rbr]
% Macro \setmathshorthands activates and defines the special characters
\begingroup
  \catcode`\[=\active
  \catcode`\]=\active
  \gdef[{\texttt{\lbr}}
  \gdef]{\texttt{\rbr}}
\@ifdefinable{\setmathshorthands}{%
    \xdef\setmathshorthands{%
      \mathcode\number`\[="8000 %
      \mathcode\number`\]="8000 %
    }%
}%
\endgroup
\makeatother
% Activate math shorthands in the math modes
\everymath{\setmathshorthands}
\everydisplay{\setmathshorthands}
%%%%%
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
    \begin{equation*}
        [x+y] \bigl[x\bigr] \left[\frac{a}{b}\right]
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
            \int_0^X f[x] dx
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]