# Matrix brackets not appearing when typeset in the typewriter style

Tags: matrices, brackets, typewriter, mathastext

I need to display all the math in the typewriter style, so I used `mathastext` to do it, but now matrix brackets are not being displayed. Everything else works fine as far as I can tell.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\renewcommand\familydefault\ttdefault
\usepackage[defaulttt]{mathastext}
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{bmatrix*}[l]
            a & (b+c)\\
            \{c\} & [d]\\
        \end{bmatrix*}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the matrix brackets are missing. How can I fix this? The answer to [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119879/math-symbols-in-tt-font) did not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math symbols in tt font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119879/math-symbols-in-tt-font)

Comment: @StefanPinnow I tried this solution with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just `\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}` last.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\renewcommand\familydefault\ttdefault
\usepackage[defaulttt]{mathastext}
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{bmatrix*}[l]
    a & (b+c)\\
    \{c\} & [d]\\
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

To get parenthesis and brackets in `\tt`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\renewcommand\familydefault\ttdefault
\usepackage[defaulttt]{mathastext}
\MTnonlettersobeymathxx     % math alphabets will act on (, ), [, ], etc...
\MTexplicitbracesobeymathxx % math alphabets will act on \{ and \}
%\MTfamily {\ttdefault}      % we will declare a math version using tt font
%\Mathastext [typewriter]    % the math version is called typewriter

\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{bmatrix*}[l]
    a & (b+c)\\
    \{c\} & [d]\\
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that some glyphs (namely, delimiters `[`, `(`, and `{` and the plus sign) are not in typewriter font.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: thanks, see my edit. But I'm not quite satisfied. It does work when removing `xits-math`…