# Using Courier font for mathematical equations (by ignoring math mode)

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Recently, I learned about the command `\texttt{...}` from Werner's (very nice) answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24848/26414).

Here is a basic example Werner gives:

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{courier}
> \begin{document}
> This is not Courier font. \texttt{This is Courier font.}
> \end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
> ```

which produces

[image: Typewriter font in LaTeX]

How can I use the same idea to describe a math equation? For example, I want to see exactly a^2+b^2 = c^2 in Courier font. Trying `\texttt{a^2+b^2=c^2}` doesn't work because `texttt`  doesn't seem to interact well with the math mode. But I precisely don't want to use double dollar signs because it displays the expression a^2+b^2=c^2 in math mode, but I explicitly want to see the symbols `^`.

For those curious, this is supposed to represent a mathematical input to a software, so I precisely want to write a^2+b^2=c^2 (in Courier font).

Comment: Does `\texttt{\detokenize{a^2+b^2=c^2}}` do the job?  Maybe [How to typset the symbol “^” (caret/circumflex/hat)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77646/106162) is useful to you here?

Comment: `\verb|a^2+b^2=c^2|` would be the usual way

Comment: @DaiBowen Yes, that works! The link was helpful too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Awesome solution. Feel free to post it as an answer. I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: `\verb` is just a basic latex command, the question must be a duplicate i'll see if i can find a suitable question...

Comment: not perfect but..